# What is the issue with this query

Tags: sql

```
select
td.employee_id,
td.date,
max(duration_from) as "logout_time",
min(duration_from) as "login_time" from 
public.timesheet_detail td
left join public.employees e on td.employee_id = e.id
left join public.time_sheets ts on td.employee_id <> ts.employee_id 
where td.date in('2022-01-11','2022-01-10')
group by td.employee_id,e.name, td.date 
order by td.date asc,e.name asc;`
```

can any one please let me know, because this query is not executing.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the error message you get.

Comment: There is no error message, this query runs continuous for infinite time with  no results.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT` - _except those who are arguments to set functions_.

Comment: You don't seem to be using any column from `time_sheets` so why not remove that left join? Besides `td.employee_id <> ts.employee_id` will multiply each row in detail with the number of rows in timesheets; I don't know why you want to do that.

Comment: The outer join with time_sheets looks incorrect, and generates more like a cartesian product of the time_sheets of the wrong (other) employees.  It probably should refer to the specific employee `e`... or at least just use the `=` operator between `td` and `ts`.

Comment: Smells like an XY-problem. What are you trying to get by using that slow non-equi-join?

Comment: td.employee_id <> ts.employee_id is the problem. What did you want to achieve with this part?

Comment: Here i want data from timesheet_detail and also i want the data from time_sheets where  employee_id in timesheet_detail dosent match to  employee_id in time_sheets.